# PowerBi DAX sum while operation

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have data from a cab-request service, which I am trying to analyse how often a trip gets cancelled before a successful trip is made. In column 2, `passengercancelled` indicates cancelled trips and `droppedoff` indicates a successful trip. I am trying to create a formula that counts how many `passengercancelled` trips happen before a `droppedoff` trip for a given passenger `passenger_id`.

I have tried the below code but I get this error:

> There's not enough memory to complete this operation. Please try again later when there may be more memory available.

```
previous_requests =
requests_with_cancel_all__[cancelled] +
MINX (
    TOPN (
        1,
        FILTER (
            requests_with_cancel_all__,
            [trip_date] > EARLIER ( [trip_date] )
                && [passenger_id] = EARLIER ( [passenger_id] )
                && EARLIER ( [current_state] ) = "droppedoff"
        ),
        [passenger_id], ASC,
        [trip_date], ASC
    ),
    requests_with_cancel_all__[cancelled]
)
```

[image: sample data]

Comment: Can you precalculate this in query editor or do you need to calculate it dynamically using DAX? `EARLIER` can significantly slow down performance.

Comment: Can you specify what values *should* go in that column in your example?